# RecyclerView with multiple Adapters and SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-recyclerview

I am using a `RecyclerView` inside a `Fragment` to display a list of categories ( as shown in the images). When a category is selected, a new `Activity` starts with a `RecyclerView`. Each item from the list has a `TextView` and an icon for favorite ( the star from the top-right corner ). Once the favorite icon is pressed, the `TextView` will be saved to another `Activity` called Favorites.

**The problem**: let's say that I select **Category A** and I press the favorite button for the first 2 items. Everything looks good, the items are saved to **Favorites**. If I select **Category B**, bamm, I find the first 2 items selected...I go to **Category C**, same thing! 
So if I check the favorite button once, it checks for all `Adapters`, like they're communicating. Why is this happening?

[image]

[image]

Although the favorite buttons are checked, I can't find the `TextView`'s from **Category B** or **C** in the **Favorites** activity.

The `Activity` that starts when a category item is selected:

```
public class CategoriesDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Adapter0 ca0;  
    RecyclerView recList;

    public CategoriesDetailActivity() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.categories_detail_activity);

        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        //  Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        bundle.getInt("id");
        int position = bundle.getInt("id");
        if (bundle.containsKey("id")) {
            position = bundle.getInt("id");
        } else {
            this.finish();
        }

        recList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
        recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recList.setLayoutManager(llm);

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                ca0 = new Adapter0(this, createList0(99));
                recList.setAdapter(ca0);
                break;
            case 1:
                ca0 = new Adapter0(this, createList1(80));
                recList.setAdapter(ca0);
                break;
             ...
          }
     }

    private List<BeanSampleList> createList0(int size) {
        List<BeanSampleList> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
            BeanSampleList ci = new BeanSampleList();
            ci.title = DataText.Text1[i];          
            ci.id = i;
            result.add(ci);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private List<BeanSampleList> createList1(int size) {
        List<BeanSampleList> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
            BeanSampleList ci = new BeanSampleList();
            ci.title = DataText.Text2[i];           
            ci.id = i;
            result.add(ci);
        }
        return result;
    }

@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (recList.getAdapter() == ca0) {
            ca0.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } if (recList.getAdapter() == ca1) {
            ca1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            // nothing
        }
    }
}
```

The `Adapter` class:

```
public class Adapter0 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter0 .ContactViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    List<BeanSampleList> postBeanSampleList;
    SharedPreference sharedPreference;
    BeanSampleList beanSampleList;

    public Adapter0 (Context context, List<BeanSampleList> postBeanSampleList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.postBeanSampleList = postBeanSampleList;
        sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return postBeanSampleList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return postBeanSampleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ContactViewHolder holder,final int i) {
        beanSampleList = (BeanSampleList) getItem(i);
        holder.vName.setText(beanSampleList.getTitle());

        if (checkFavoriteItem(beanSampleList)) {
            holder.btnFavourite.setLiked(true);
            holder.btnFavourite.setTag("active");
        } else {
            holder.btnFavourite.setLiked(false);
            holder.btnFavourite.setTag("deactive");
        }               
    }

    @Override
    public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.categories_detail_adapter, viewGroup, false);

        return new ContactViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    public class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnLikeListener {

        protected TextView vName;
        protected LikeButton btnFavourite;

        public ContactViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            vName =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.t1);
            btnFavourite = (LikeButton)  v.findViewById(R.id.favouritesToggle);

            btnFavourite.setOnLikeListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void liked(LikeButton likeButton) {
            final int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (likeButton.getId() == btnFavourite.getId()) {
                String tag = btnFavourite.getTag().toString();
                if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("deactive")) {
                    sharedPreference.addFavorite(context, postBeanSampleList.get(position));
                    btnFavourite.setTag("active");
                    btnFavourite.setLiked(true);
                }
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(likeButton, "Added to Favorites!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                snackbar.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void unLiked(LikeButton likeButton) {
            final int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (likeButton.getId() == btnFavourite.getId()) {
                sharedPreference.removeFavorite(context, postBeanSampleList.get(position));
                btnFavourite.setTag("deactive");
                btnFavourite.setLiked(false);

                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(likeButton, "Removed from Favorites!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                snackbar.show();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean checkFavoriteItem(BeanSampleList checkProduct) {
        boolean check = false;
        List<BeanSampleList> favorites = sharedPreference.loadFavorites(context);
        if (favorites != null) {
            for (BeanSampleList product : favorites) {
                if (product.equals(checkProduct)) {
                    check = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return check;
    }
}
```

For the past 2 days I've been trying to fix this but I just can't figure out what's causing this. I also tried to use different `Adapters` for each position but with no success.

```
public class BeanSampleList {

    public int id;
    public String title;
    public String subTitle;
    public String bottomTitle;
    public String imageView;

    public BeanSampleList() {
        super();
    }

    public BeanSampleList(int id, String title, String subTitle, String bottomTitle, String imageView) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.subTitle = subTitle;
        this.bottomTitle = bottomTitle;
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    public String getSubTitle() {
        return subTitle;
    }

    public void setSubTitle(String subTitle) {
        this.subTitle = subTitle;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getTitleBottom() {
        return bottomTitle;
    }

    public void setTitleBottom(String bottomTitle) {
        this.bottomTitle = bottomTitle;
    }
    public String getImageView() {
        return imageView;
    }

    public void setImageView(String imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        BeanSampleList other = (BeanSampleList) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Thank you so much and sorry for my english.

Comment: I think you are access and binding the same store favorite value in all the Item views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is in your id generation for `BeanSampleList`

```
 private List<BeanSampleList> createList0(int size) {
        List<BeanSampleList> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
            BeanSampleList ci = new BeanSampleList();
            ci.title = DataText.Text1[i];          
            ci.id = i;
            result.add(ci);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private List<BeanSampleList> createList1(int size) {
        List<BeanSampleList> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
            BeanSampleList ci = new BeanSampleList();
            ci.title = DataText.Text2[i];           
            ci.id = i;
            result.add(ci);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

You need to generate unique id for your BeanSamleList objects in createList* method. As in your current code the objects are the same from the equals method side (their id are from 0 to list_size range).

Or add some unique modifier to compare in equal, like add the position of parent list

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        BeanSampleList other = (BeanSampleList) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (listId != other.listId) 
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I have added the `BeanSampleList` class so you can see exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: well, the answer is still the same.  You're creating BeanSampleList objects in  createList* methods and do not take into account the "position" that your received through intent, because your're generating id for them from 0 to size range.

Comment: Woohoo!! it kinda works. At first when `int i = 0`  the first item from each adapter was selected ( not sure why ), so I changed it to `int i = 1`. I guess tomorrow I will need to create 60 `if` statements... wish there was another solution. Anyways, I will make the changes tomorrow and if everything will work fine I will accept your answer. Thank you!!

Comment: No no no, you should simplify it! Developer should be lazy to avoid writing a lot of duplicate code! :)

Comment: Everything seems to be working fine, thank you @aelimill. Also, I agree with what you said, that I should avoid duplicate code, right now I have no idea how I can do that but I'll try...

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a different way to uniquely identify each BeanSampleList element. Just matching id is not good enough. Perhaps you could also match the titles if you know they will be unique. Or generate unique Ids for each of these elements say by dividing the integer domain in different ranges e.g. 1 to 1000000 is for category 1, 1000001 to 2000000 for category 2 and so on.